# XMLHTTP POST Not Enough Storage

Tags: vba, excel, xmlhttprequest, serverxmlhttp

I've written a function in VBA (Excel) to process an API request. For small (<150MB or so) requests it works just fine, but for large requests (>150 MB up to 300-400MB of returned data) I get:

> error: 2147024882 (8007000e) Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.

Below is the code (with non-applicable pieces removed):

```
Function SendHTTPRequest(sURL As String, Optional sGETorPOST As String = "POST", Optional sHeaders2DArray As Variant, Optional sGetBodyOrPostArgs As String) As msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP60
    Dim aheaders() As Variant, i As Long
    If sGETorPOST <> "GET" And sGETorPOST <> "POST" Then Exit Function
    If IsMissing(sHeaders2DArray) Then
        ReDim aheaders(0 To 0, 0 To 1)
        aheaders(0, 0) = "User-Agent"
        aheaders(0, 1) = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
    Else
        ReDim aheaders(LBound(sHeaders2DArray) To UBound(sHeaders2DArray), LBound(sHeaders2DArray, 2) To UBound(sHeaders2DArray, 2))
        aheaders = sHeaders2DArray
    End If
    Set SendHTTPRequest = New msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP60
    SendHTTPRequest.Open sGETorPOST, sURL, False
    For i = LBound(aheaders) To UBound(aheaders)
        SendHTTPRequest.setRequestHeader aheaders(i, 0), aheaders(i, 1)
    Next
    If sGETorPOST = "POST" Then SendHTTPRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    SendHTTPRequest.send (sGetBodyOrPostArgs) '<-- Error occurs here
End Function
```

I've been tackling this problem for two days. I was originally doing the POST request wrong and fixed it, and I changed from XMLHTTP to ServerXMLHTTP.

Here's the applicable code calling the function:

```
aheaders(0, 0) = "User-Agent"
aheaders(0, 1) = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
aheaders(1, 0) = "X-Requested-With"
aheaders(1, 1) = "[redacted]"
aheaders(2, 0) = "Authorization"
aheaders(2, 1) = "Basic " & EncodeBase64(USER & ":" & PASS)
sURL = URLAPI & "/api/2.0/fo/scan/"
sArgs = "action=fetch&scan_ref=" & sRef & "&mode=extended&output_format=json"
Set httpRequest = SendHTTPRequest(sURL, "POST", aheaders, sArgs)
```

I've been testing in Excel 2010, 2013, and 2016. It's definitely not a resource issue. I'm running a Xeon W3550 with 12GB ram and a 500GB SSD that's less than half full.

Is there something I can do to fix this code, or is there an alternate way to make the API request?

Comment: You could try making the request asynchronous - `SendHTTPRequest.Open sGETorPOST, sURL, True` - and repeatedly reading from the [responseStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms759211(v=vs.85).aspx) property of the request. Not sure if this will help though. Details of how to work with the ADODB.Stream object are [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675032(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I'll give that a shot but I have a feeling it won't help, being that responseStream is read-only.

Interestingly, I tried making it asyncronyous and waiting for the readystate to be 4, and it never was... it stayed readystate 3 for over half an hour before I killed it.